# Emacs indentation for html (web-mode) doesn't work properly

Tags: html, emacs, indentation, emacs24

I'm using [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) in Emacs to get syntax highlighting and indentation for PHP and HTML.

If I have this code in a .php file

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

And then put the cursor on the middle line and press tab then nothing happens.

I want it to look like this:

```
<p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

If I put the text in a tag on a single line and try to indent, it works.

This:

```
<p>
<a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
</p>
```

turns into this, which it should

```
<p>
    <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
</p>
```

---

My .emacs file

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsp\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))

(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-indent-style 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, the indentation works for me, what version of web-mode are you using?

Comment: I'm using web-mode 8.0.9 in Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: I am using the same version, indentation works for the code `<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>`. Does indentation fail for you even when you have only the above code in php file?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a single line or multiple lines? It does work for a single line but not multiple. Though it seems to work in a .html file without enabling web-mode. Though not in a .php file.

Comment: Multiple lines, just like in your question, I do not know how to post multi-line code in comments :)

Comment: Okay, well it doesn't work.

Comment: This is strange, it works for me, have you tried with `emacs -Q` if it still does not work then maybe this is a bug in web-mode, you should report it on its github repo.

Comment: OK the indentation is not working for me now sorry the noise, actually it works for files with `html` extension but fails for files with `php` extension this is definitely a bug you should report it.

Comment: Reported https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/192

Answer (score 9):

try put these setting in a hook function:

```
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
    (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
    (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 4)
    (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
    (setq web-mode-indent-style 4)
)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you add this

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any difference