# How to enable indentation on Emacs in web-mode?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'm currently using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 with web-mode enabled. Everything works just fine but Tab key doesn't work like the way it used to. Indentation feature of web-mode also doesn't work perfectly. How can I configure my Emacs to enable Tab key work it just like before?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of web-mode.
Could give examples of indentation issues ?
Moreover "Tab key doesn't work like the way it used to" does not mean anything. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: When I use tab key, it works as shift + tab.  I have to use spaces instead of tab.

Comment: I'm not only one to have this problem. Similar problem was posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648629/emacs-indentation-for-html-web-mode-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: please post an issue on github